# Java Spring Boot Prometheus metrics adding log4j2_events_total metric

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, metrics, prometheus

I have added dependencies for Prometheus and Actuactor:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
  <artifactId>micrometer-core</artifactId>
  <version>${micrometer-registry-prometheus.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
  <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
  <version>${micrometer-registry-prometheus.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

But if i go to endpoint */actuator/promehteus* the **log4j2_events_total** metric is not in place even though i also added **log4j2** dependency from Spring Boot starter, am i missing some additional configuration for that ?

Comment: you mean you've added `spring-boot-starter-log4j2` as a dependency?

Comment: Yes i have added it

Answer (score 1):

Try this, I created a new project and it worked for me after adding below dependencies. Make sure to add **spring-boot-starter-web** dependency and exclude **spring-boot-starter-logging** from it to avoid `SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.` ERROR.

```
<!-- ########################################### -->
<!-- spring Management dependencies for Actuator -->
<!-- ########################################### -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
    <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
</dependency>
<!-- ####################### -->
<!-- log4j dependencies -->
<!-- ####################### -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<!-- Add Log4j2 Dependency -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

you can find a sample project at below location:-
https://github.com/ishivesh/demo-processor